# Get the sum of a datatable column

Tags: c#, linq

I want to build a linq query something like this:

```
Double n = dtCurrentDateRows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => (String)r["DATE"] == "10/09/2013").Sum(r => (Double)r["CALLS"]);
```

This is what I wrote so far:

```
string c = "CALLS";

string ymd= "2013-10-09";

string date = String.Format("'{0}'", DateTime.Parse(ymd).ToString("M/dd/yyyy"));

Double total = dtCurrentDateRows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => (String)r["DATE"] == date).Sum(r => (Double)r[c]);
```

Please suggest how to get the sum of a datatable column?

edit: I am trying tdo compute the sum of "Calls" coulmn where date is "2013-10-09". But I don't know how do I pass it in linq query.

**Update**
I simply wrote this line and it works

string ymd = "10/9/2013"; // this comes from database

string date = DateTime.Parse(ymd).ToString("M/dd/yyyy");

Double sum = dtCurrentDateRows.AsEnumerable().Where(r => (String)r["DATE"] == date).Sum(r => (Double)r[columnName]);

But in case when the column have some blank values it gives 0.0.

**Can anybody suggest me how to check if calls is blank then don't sum otherwise SUM all the values.**

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your code isn't working? Do you get any exception or error message? Why don't you use [`DataTable.Compute` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like `dt.Compute("Sum(DATE)", "");` And how do you think you get sum of your dates? What is the type of your `DATE` column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Compute() method like this:

```
object sum = dtCurrentDateRows.Compute("Sum(CALLS)", string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat,"date = #{0}#",YourDateVariable));
```

To get the double right away use,instead of object do this:

```
double sum = (double)/*rest of expression like above*/;
```

Comment: The problem with compute is it does not compute correctly when any of the column value is blank/null.

Comment: i know of that problem with compute but i made a datatable with 2 columns(1 datetime and 1 double)and even if some of the values in the double(your CALLS column)column are null it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Note: if your date field has time values, use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime()` to remove it before comparing ).

```
System.DateTime myDate = new System.DateTime(2013, 10, 9); //Year, Month, Date

var n = dtCurrentDateRows.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => r.Field<System.DateTime>("DATE") == myDate)
                  .Sum(r=> r.Field<Double>("CALLES"));
```

Comment: I cannot hard code the date. It will come from database.

Comment: Then replace it with your variable date.

Comment: The replace gives me error "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: You probably need to convert your variable to `System.DateTime` type.

Comment: Thanks Kaf for helping me in resolving the issue. This is what I wrote:
 string ymd = "2013-10-09"; // this definitely will come from database column
                   System.DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Parse(ymd).ToString("M/dd/yyyy")); //Year, Month, Date

                    var sum = dtCurrentDateRows.AsEnumerable()
                                      .Where(r => r.Field<System.DateTime>("DATE") == myDate)
                                      .Sum(r => r.Field<Double>("CALLS"));